# Celery on Apache server throws unexpected IOError

Tags: python, linux, django, apache

I am working on a Django project where users can execute python scripts through a web UI. I'm using [Wooey](https://github.com/wooey/Wooey) to create the UI. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is used as the task queue (RabbitMQ as broker). The site runs on a small Apache server via CentOS (not sure about Linux version).

I've managed to get my site to run the test scripts provided by Wooey and a couple of my own scripts. 
The problem comes up when I try to execute a certain large script through the site on this server. This script runs fine at a localhost (i.e. starting up my site via manage.py runserver). However, a certain error pops up every time I try to submit this script to the task queue on the server (through the website):

```
 -------------- celery@RK-DEP-APACHE01.company.local v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.1.1503-Core
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x15fcc10 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . skipid.celery.debug_task
  . wooey.tasks.WooeyTask
  . wooey.tasks.submit_script

[2016-06-10 10:33:59,386: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2016-06-10 10:33:59,401: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2016-06-10 10:33:59,426: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-06-10 10:34:00,435: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-06-10 10:34:00,454: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@RK-DEP-APACHE01.company.local ready.
[2016-06-10 10:34:03,275: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: wooey.tasks.submit_script[0dea8557-a69f-4685-8ba4-0a                  675461a76d]
[2016-06-10 10:34:03,314: ERROR/MainProcess] Task wooey.tasks.submit_script[0dea8557-a69f-4685-8ba4-0a675461a76                  d] raised unexpected: IOError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wooey/tasks.py", line 49, in submit_script
    command = utils.get_job_commands(job=job)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wooey/backend/utils.py", line 72, in get_job_commands
    subproc_dict = param.get_subprocess_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wooey/models/core.py", line 333, in get_subprocess_value
    value = self.value
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wooey/models/core.py", line 405, in value
    raise IOError
IOError
```

I've made sure to give the server permission to write to all the proper ouput directories, and set permissions on all of them to 777 but that doesn't help.
Since the script runs through a locally hosted site, I think this is some sort of permissions issue.

Any and all suggestions appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The `raise IOError` in line 405 masks the real error. can you change that line in the lib to just `raise` and see if the traceback changes.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot!

Comment: Please add the solution to the problem as an answer to yourself!

Comment: Will do! Getting used to using Stackoverflow at the moment!

Answer (score 2):

I followed [Klaus D.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) suggestion and deleted `IOError` from line 405 in the Wooey `core.py` file.

Turns out that the error was indeed caused by a permission issue I thought I'd rectified earlier. Some new files created by Wooey were getting the default OS permission settings, thus disallowing the server (or user that started up the server) from writing to and reading those files.

**Edit**: All folders created by Wooey had the correct permission parameters, but some of the files got the default parameters instead of those that I had intended.